# ForeignKeyConstraint: false match with empty string and whitespace

Tags: c#, database, string

I have a DataTable with 3x string columns, a constraint and I am trying to fill it with unique rows. The first row adds nicely but unfortunately when I am trying to add a second one with unique values I am receiving a false constraint error message.

I have distilled my custom class to the minimum and added an extra check for the two values before trying to add them, but the result is contradictory.

Here it goes:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace DataTableForeignKey
{
    public class Symbols : IEnumerable
    {
        protected DataTable fTable = new DataTable();
        protected DataColumn fCategoryColumn = new DataColumn("Category", typeof(string));
        protected DataColumn fNameColumn = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
        protected DataColumn fValueColumn = new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string));

        public Symbols()
        {
            fTable.Columns.Add(fCategoryColumn);
            fTable.Columns.Add(fNameColumn);
            fTable.Columns.Add(fValueColumn);

            // Temporarily disabled
            //fTable.Constraints.Add(new ForeignKeyConstraint(fNameColumn, fCategoryColumn));

            fTable.Constraints.Add(new ForeignKeyConstraint(fValueColumn, fCategoryColumn));
        }

        public virtual void Add(string aCategory, string aName, string aValue)
        {
            var lRow = fTable.NewRow();

            lRow[fCategoryColumn] = aCategory;
            lRow[fNameColumn] = aName;
            lRow[fValueColumn] = aValue;
            fTable.Rows.Add(lRow);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return fTable.Rows.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lSymbols = new Symbols();
            var lWhitespace = " ";
            var lEmptyString = string.Empty;

            if (lWhitespace != lEmptyString)
            {
                lSymbols.Add("Whitespace", "Separator", lWhitespace);
                lSymbols.Add("Prefix", "Command", lEmptyString);
                // The second Add() throws the following exception:
                // System.Data.ConstraintException: 'Column 'Value' is
                // constrained to be unique.  Value '' is already present.'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can an empty string match with a whitespace?

Many thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: It is normal behavior, ms sql server  follows ANSI 92 specification https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces. Most interesting  - you can't override such behavior by any SET statement

Comment: Why are you adding a foreign key constraint with columns from the same table? I'm a little surprised it allows you to do that.

Comment: Thanks vitalygolub. Apparently I have to redesign my code then. :(

Comment: Crowcoder: because I would like to allow adding the same "Value" to the table multiple times, but only one per "Category". It is not really an SQL solution though, it is the symbol database of a parser that I was hoping to be able to implement with DataTable. I probably have to build something more complex with the Dictionary<> class. I'm still hesitating about it as DataTable has all the features I'd need for the task.

Comment: That would be a `UniqueConstraint`, which by the way, does not fail to set empty string and space.

Comment: Wow man, I should have thought of that. Send it in as an answer, I give you a big thumbs up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `UniqueConstraint`. So you can change that line of code to:

```
fTable.Constraints.Add(new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] { fValueColumn, fCategoryColumn}));
```